# Simulation software for reflections?

Tags: windows, simulation

Anyone knows a software for simulating reflections?
I need to create a mirror which will be spinning and a beam of light shining onto it. The goal is to find the right hight/angle of beam, position/angle/size of the mirror so that a specific shape will be created by shining the light at spinning mirrors. Kind of how laser projectors work.